# How to replace html property using regex in a specific tag

Tags: javascript, html, string

I need to replace the value of "p-type" to "p-kind" only in the "button" tags using regex, for example:

input:

```
<button p-type="foo">
    anything
</button>
```

output:

```
<button p-kind="foo">
    anything
</button>
```

the "p-type" property may not be the first one, but even then it should be changed to "p-kind", for example:

input :

```
<button anythingProperty p-type="foo">
    anything
</button>
```

output:

```
<button anythingProperty p-kind="foo">
    anything
</button>
```

If the tag is not a button the "p-type" remains, for example a `div` with this property will not be changed.

I can change using the following expression: `(p-type)([a-zA-Z0-9:]*)`.
But that changes for all and I would like to group only the ones that are `<button></button>`

Comment: You do realize that `p-type` is an invalid HTML5 attribute, right? Use `data-*` attributes instead. Also, use a proper DOMParser, not RegExp.

Comment: You can use 2 capture groups `(<button\b[^<>]* p-)type(="[^"]*"[^<>]*>)`  https://regex101.com/r/r8lmwD/1 and replace with `$1kind$2` but consider using a dom parser.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan thanks for the answer. This component I'm using is customized and it has this property

Comment: @Thefourthbird this apparently worked. thank you so much!

Comment: @ramosjc You are welcome, but consider using the answer of Roko C. Buljan instead.

Comment: Like 80% of Regex tagged questions, this is a possible [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/).

Answer (score 5):

- Don't use invalid HTML5 attributes. Use [`data-*` attributes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes) instead
- Don't use RegExp. Use a [DOMParser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser/parseFromString) instead

```js
const input = `<button style="color:red;" data-type="foo">anything</button>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
const btn = doc.querySelector("button");
btn.dataset.type = "bar";

console.log(btn.outerHTML)
```

Or, on order to modify the **data attribute name** completely, i.e: change `data-type="foo"` into `data-kind="foo"`:

```js
const input = `<button style="color:red;" data-type="foo">anything</button>`;

const doc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(input, "text/html");
const btn = doc.querySelector("button");
const dataValue = btn.dataset.type; // store the old value
delete btn.dataset.type; // delete old data attribute
btn.dataset.kind = dataValue; // add new data attribute

console.log(btn.outerHTML)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but in this example you are changing the value of "data-type", but how would I change the name of the property instead of the value

Comment: @ramosjc refresh the page. I edited the answer meanwhile